# Callback - copy object values and then reset them to value 0

Tags: javascript, callback

Case is to copy `data` to `savedData` and then clear `data.value1` and `data.value2` with value `0`

But clearing is executing before saving and saved are values `0`

```js
var data = {
  value1: 1,
  value2: 2
}

var savedData = [];

function saveData() {
  var saved = savedData.push(data); 
  return saved;
}

function clearData(num){
  if (num > 0) {
    data.value1 = 0;
    data.value2 = 0;
  }

  console.log(savedData);
}

clearData(saveData());
```

Comment: It's not an issue of timing, it's an issue of there being just *one* object which you pass around by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just passing the reference of `data` to `savedData`.Use [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which will create a deep copy

```js
var data = {
  value1: 1,
  value2: 2
}

var savedData = [];

function saveData() {
  var saved = savedData.push(Object.assign({}, data));
  return saved;
}

function clearData(num) {
  if (num > 0) {
    data.value1 = 0;
    data.value2 = 0;
  }
  console.log(savedData);
  console.log('data ', data)
}

clearData(saveData());
```